# Can Cloudant API Keys be deleted?

Tags: cloudant

Cloudant provides an API for creating API keys by issuing a POST to /_api/v2/api_keys

https://docs.cloudant.com/authorization.html#creating-api-keys

However, I do not see any documentation which states that an API Key can be deleted, so my assumption is that instead, you just remove the key from the authorization list of all your databases and stop using it.

Is that the correct approach?

Answer (score 6):

You can remove an API key from the dashboard by going to Databases -> Permissions. Hover over the API key you would like to delete and click the "X" that appears once you are hovered over the API key.

To remove an API key using the Cloudant API, you will need to issue an HTTP PUT to the `_security` API endpoint providing an updated list of usernames that does *not* include the API key you would like to delete. [See the API documentation on modifying permissions.](https://docs.cloudant.com/authorization.html#modifying-permissions)

Answer (score 0):

While the other answer is useful on its own, it doesn't actually answer the question, which is specifically about the possibility to delete an API key and not just remove it from the authorization list.

From the [documentation](https://docs.cloudant.com/authorization.html):

> By removing the API key from the list of users that have access permissions, the effect is to delete the API key.

So it does seem that there's no way to completely delete an API key, and removing it is indeed the right approach. Since an API key without any permissions can't do anything, it doesn't really matter.